# Lync 2013 Modality.ModalityStateChanged callback not always being called

Tags: lync-2013, skype-for-business, lync-client-sdk

So the issue I'm having only recently started after an update to the Lync client somewhere around version 15.0.4849.1000. The issue revolves around app sharing conferences, which I have working fine still in 2016 SFB and anything prior to 15.0.4849.1000.

The core issue as far as I can tell deals with Modality.BeginConnect, the passed in callback does not get called. Although, I have had it get called when I'm debugging, stepping through the code and hitting breakpoints, etc. So that leads me to think that normally maybe something's not getting initialized in time, or some sort of race condition, but I haven't been able to pin down exactly what makes it function correctly in that case.

EDIT: I just realized another exception occurs during the call to BeginConnect:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Microsoft.Lync.Model.dll

Additional information: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80F10083
```

And that HRESULT translates to: "The operation is disabled by capability". What in the world does that mean?

The odd thing is (or seems odd to me) that even though the callback is never called, I do receive a ModalityStateChanged event for ModalityState.Connected...

So if you have any ideas what would perhaps cause that, please share!

---

I don't think these this is related, but a call to this:

```
m_aeConversationWnd = AutomationElement.FromHandle(m_ConversationWindow.Handle);
```

shortly before calling BeginConnect, fails with the exception:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in UIAutomationClientsideProviders.dll

Additional information: Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

Comment: I've been seeing these types of problems in Lync Client SDK for awhile now and just had to work around them in wacky ways. I think it comes down to the Lync Client SDK being "static" but the SFB (Lync) Client keeps being updated and breaking the SDK in this way (i.e. COM incompatibility).  This question is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33229251/no-client-sdk-for-skype-for-business-2016

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I ended up doing. What I did to "fix" it doesn't seem to make a whole lot of sense, so I'm not going to bother answering with it lol. Thanks for the confirmation, I'm not crazy!